# Android Zbar barcode scan using PictureCallback instead of PreviewCallback

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode-scanner, zbar

I am trying to scan barcodes after taking a picture of them using the Camera Activity. However the byte[] data from onPictureTaken() is different from onPreviewFrame() (the one used in the examples). Is there any way to convert the byte[] data from onPictureTaken() so that the imagescanner can pick up the barcode?

```
Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
barcode.setData(data);
int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);
```

The main problem is that in the above code if I use the byte[] data from onPictureTaken then result is 0, but it should be 1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have example convert. Try it and tell me if works:

```
 Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "NV21");
 barcode.setData(data);   
 barcode = barcode.convert("Y800");
```

[Here is more info](http://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/discussion/2308158/thread/ce0d36f8/)

Comment: Hi thanks this helps. Unfortunately it is not robust. 1 out of maybe 6 times it will return a 1 rest is 0 still. Do you think this has to do with the camera focus?

Comment: It maybe has something with it or camera resolution is too small - it is hard to say